# First business day of the current month - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I get the first business day of the current month?
Without create a function, only select.
something like that:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1), GETDATE()), 101)
```

somebody knows please?

Thanks.

Comment: What if January 1st is a Monday, does that count as the first business day?

Comment: This all depends on the current region etc. Even inside a country there are different business days (example Germany where different Bundesländer have different public holidays). You will first need to define what a business day is

Comment: yes, in this case only I want dont count Sunday and Saturday.. dont matter holidays.

Comment: Just throwing in my .02, but I think a date table would help you greatly here.

Comment: Ok, but what about the different countries that work on a Sunday and don't work on a Friday? [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend)

Comment: Additionally, the business calendar can be unique to a business.  Where I work we use a modified 445 (4wk , 4w, 5wk) fiscal calendar.  In our SQL DBF we have a simple control table that defines all fiscal periods.  Thus no math, no errors due to leap year, and no unexpected issues when Jan 1st is in the last fiscal period of the previous year.  In summary, just make a table with the dates you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Simple case statement could do it

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 1
        ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)
        END
```

Answer (score 3):

This will literally give you what you're asking for -- the first business day in a month if we define a business day as "any day that's not a Saturday or a Sunday". But this is is a very narrow definition of "business day" that is not appropriate when taking into account holidays and cultural differences, so it generalizes poorly. The typical solution for this problem is to create a table that actually holds the working days (which is generated somewhere just before he year, or calculated in advance if that's feasible), and simply look it up in that.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,
    CASE
        (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) + @@DATEFIRST - 1) % 7
        WHEN 6 THEN 2 
        WHEN 7 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
)
```

This solution uses `@@DATEFIRST` to avoid any language issues -- using `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ...)` on its own or `DATENAME()` only works if we assume a specific region.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more flexibility in your `SELECT` statement, you might be able to use something like this:

```
;With Daterange As
(
    Select  DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()), 0) As Date Union All
    Select  DateAdd(Day, 1, Date) As Date
    From    DateRange
    Where   Date < DateAdd(Day, 6, DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()), 0))
)
Select  Convert(Date, Min(Date)) FirstBusinessDay 
From    Daterange 
Where   DatePart(WeekDay, Date) Not In (7, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Datename(dw, Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate())) = 'Saturday' THEN Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 3, Getdate())
         WHEN Datename(dw, Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate())) = 'Sunday' THEN Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 2, Getdate())
         ELSE Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate())
       END
```

**Explanation :**

1. Find the first day of the month.

   `Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate())`
2. Then check the day of the previous date by using `Datename` function.

   `Datename(dw, Dateadd(dd, -Datepart(dd, Getdate()) + 1, Getdate()))`
3. If the `Datename` is **Saturday** the **add** `2` days to the **first day of the month** . if it is `sunday` then **add** `1` day to the **first day of the month** `else` get the **first day of the month**