# How to schedule SQL agent job on first week day of every month?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I want to be schedule my package on first week day(i.e exclude sat,sun)of every month.
Suppose first day of month falls on Saturday or Sunday then monday only should execute the program.
Suppose first day of months falls on any week day(mon,tue,wed,thu,fri) then execute the program on same day.
Please tell me how to set up the schedule in sql agent ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule it to run daily and just check the date in your code and only execute if the dates match.

```
--WorkDay of current month
DECLARE @FoM DATETIME
        SELECT
        @FoM =
        CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 1
        ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)
        END 

IF @FoM = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
BEGIN
...your code to execute...
END
```

[First business day of the current month - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109823/first-business-day-of-the-current-month-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

You can schedule the job in the first Monday of every month as given below in the SQL Agent schedule properties of the job:
[image: Scheduling First Monday of Every month]