# Calculating every month 8th business day

Tags: sql-server

How to get 8th Business day, start checking to see if the data exists.  If it does exist Set and represents more than 50% of the loans - Set the Verified Date to that Day

Thank You Regards Shehroz

Comment: Sample data, desired output, what have you tried youtrself?

Comment: how to get 8th business day of the current month in sql server how

Comment: Find the first business day... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27110176/6167855... then figure out what day of the week that is with `DATEPART(dw,yourDate)` then add the appropriate number of days using `DATEADD()` ensuring to account for weekends.

Comment: i will check thank you

Comment: Why dv for this post ?!

Comment: DV Means @FLICKER

Comment: down voting your question. Question is valid and useful and challenging, to you should not get negative point for that. Check out my answer.

Comment: DV = down vote and though i didn't do it, it was likely due to the ambiguity of the OP. Your comment " 
how to get 8th business day of the current month in sql server" is more clear than the original post which asks much more without providing a lot of details like a sample data set, expected results. etc. Check our MCVE here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @scsimon, just to mention, I did not point to you :). I don't like the people who dv w/o adding a comment :(

Comment: @FLICKER i understand it wasn't me, but most people saw this question earlier before seeing this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170862/if-there-is-at-least-50-of-the-funded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @D date = '2012-12-01'   -- Supply 1st of Month

Select D=max(D) 
 From (
        Select Top 8 D=DateAdd(DD,N,@D) 
         From (Select N From (Values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)) N(N) ) A
         Where DatePart(DW,DateAdd(DD,N,@D)) between 2 and 6 
       ) A
```

Returns

```
2012-12-12
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result, however my answer lists all 8th business days from specific date.

It does not consider holidays though. With small changes you can consider holidays too.

You can use `top 1` on the last `select` to get only one date.

```
DECLARE @start date
SELECT @start = '20160101'

;WITH n AS (
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects
), dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n - 1, @start) Dt
    FROM n
), dayNum AS (
    SELECT Dt, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Dt) WeekDayName
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Dt) DayNumber
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Dt) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
)
SELECT Dt, DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Dt) WeekDayName
FROM dayNum
WHERE DayNumber % 8 = 0
ORDER BY Dt
```