# SQL Server : first business day of month

Tags: sql-server

How can I incorporate a holiday table into the SQL below? The result returns the first business day, but since 1/1/18 was a Monday holiday I need business day 2.

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME;
SET @DATE = '1/1/2018';

SELECT 
    CASE
       WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0)) = 'Saturday'
          THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0) + 2
       WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0)) = 'Sunday'
          THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0) + 2
       WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0)) = 'Monday'
          THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0) + 1
       ELSE DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @DATE), 0)
   END;
```

Comment: I propose to forget about magic formula to calculate business day and simply define [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) for next 10 years.

Comment: This has been addressed multiple times and it's not clear that you've tried looking... https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=first+business+day+of+the+month

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations And for heaven's sake don't mix MM and mm in the same query. Makes my eyes water trying to unravel the codes.

Comment: I have tried looking in prior posts, but as a SQL novice I was hoping to find a clear resolution.  With that said, I have no control over the company’s holiday table, is there not a quick case to add?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, you can check this sqlscript as you mention, I am given a 3 different dates to check proper answer :

```
Declare @date date = '01/01/2018' --getdate()

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0) + 1
        ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)
        END

set @date = '04/01/2018' --getdate()

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0) + 1
        ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)
        END

set @date = '09/01/2018' --getdate()

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0) + 1
        ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, @date), 0)
        END
```

Please refer :- [First business day of the current month - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109823/first-business-day-of-the-current-month-sql-server)