# Select the first weekday of the next Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to modify someone else's code I found here to find the first weekday of next month [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109823/first-business-day-of-the-current-month-sql-server):

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Saturday'
        THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 2
    WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Sunday'
        THEN dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0) + 1
    ELSE dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)
    END
```

Here is what I have come up with (which doesn't work):

```
select CASE 
                WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, eomonth(dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()),1), 0 )) = 'Saturday'
                    THEN eomonth(dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0),1) + 2
                WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, eomonth(dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()),1), 0)) = 'Sunday'
                    THEN eomonth(dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0),1) + 1
                ELSE eomonth(dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 1),1)
                end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What SQL implementation is it? Oracle, sql server, mysql, ....

Comment: I think it's SQLite

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think there is a `DATEDIFF` method in Sqlite. There is in Sql server. Find out for certain, and [edit] your question to add the relevant tag .

Comment: Please also reference your research, which I suspect is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109823/first-business-day-of-the-current-month-sql-server), and explain why it's not working (which could be that you're.using an SQL server answer with Sqlite, which won't work.)

Comment: It turns out I was mistaken and I'm using SQL server. I went ahead and made the relevant edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query implementation looks like for SQL server. You may use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or `EOMONTH` function to get first day of next month, then use DATENAME in CASE expression to decide the first weekday like below (SQL Server only).

```
-- get first day of next month using DATEFROMPARTS
Declare @NextMonthFirstDate datetime = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE())+1,1)

-- then use CASE expression 
Select CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @NextMonthFirstDate) = 'Sunday'
                THEN @NextMonthFirstDate + 1
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @NextMonthFirstDate) = 'Saturday'
                THEN @NextMonthFirstDate + 2
            ELSE @NextMonthFirstDate END as FirstWeekDayOfnextMonth
```